# Passing jQuery variable to PHP - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to pass a jQuery value to PHP as follows:

```
var your_var_value=1200;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "scripts/php/controllers/tariff.fare.controller.php",
    data: { var_value: your_var_value},
    error:function(request){alert(request.statusText)},
    success:function(result){
        alert(your_var_value);
    }
});
```

To the following:

```
<?php

require_once('models/sql.php');
require_once('models/server.php');
require_once('models/journey.php');

class TariffFareController {

    // If there is no fixed fare, use route calc
    if ($fixed_fare_result == null) {

        $distance=$_POST['var_value'];

        if ($distance > 1100) {
            $fare = 222.00;
        }
        else {
            $fare = 111.00;
        }

        //MORE CODE

}
```

But when I do this I get a `500 Internal Server Error`

I know the URL I am passing this to is correct, any ideas ?

Comment: You will need to look into your webserver log files to try and identify the 500 error.

Comment: Check your server logs. It will give some clue.

Comment: You can also run php -l filename to check if any syntax error is there.

Comment: Can you open the file `scripts/php/controllers/tariff.fare.controller.php` without errors? If not, jquery isn't responsible

Comment: This has nothing to do with jquery/javascript. The problem with is with your php code and there is not enough code here to determine the problem.

Comment: yeah as Philipp said.  Can you navigate to the controller in the url ok? e.g www.domain.co.uk/scripts/php/controllers/tariff.fare.controller.php if you can then the php file is fine.  It then would suggest a server config error perhaps your access_log/error_log files would point you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an end brace and your if statement needs to be within a function.